# Remove local file on one branch in a git directory, but keep it locally on another branch

Tags: git

I have a git repository with two branches. One is the `master` branch where my code is, while the other is called `gh-pages` (for documentation on [github pages](https://pages.github.com/)).
Now, at the `master` branch, some files are created after I run my program, and I want them to be visible locally (but untracked, e.g. log files). However, I do not want these files to be visible on my other branch. So I do:

```
$ python program.py  # On master: create test1 and test2
$ ls test?  # shows test1 and test2 are here
$ git checkout gh-pages
$ ls test?  # shows test1 and test2 are here, but I don't want them on this branch
$ rm test?
$ git checkout master
$ ls test?  # test1 and test2 are gone, but they should still be here
```

Are there any way to have local files on one git branch, but not on another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git stash` can help you saving untracked files and switching between branches.
[git stash man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Example: you are on `master` and want to switch to `gh-pages`.
`$ git stash save --all <stash name>` (1)
`$ git checkout gh-pages` (2)
Working on `gh-pages`...
`$ git checkout master` (3)
`$ git stash pop <stash name>` (4)

(1) Saving untracked files **and** ignored files to make working directory clean.
(2) Switching to `gh-pages`
(3) Going back to `master`
(4) Retrieving untracked files you saved previously.

Edited command to match you requirements.
To only stash untracked files: `--include-untracked`
To stash ignored and untracked files: `--all` (no need to repeat `--include-untracked`)

Comment: That seems to work. I need some more time with it before I'm comfortable, but it is like that with most things I guess. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `git stash`is a very powerful tool, read man pages it worths it.

Comment: I think I used a slightly wrong terminology. When I said they are untracked, I actually meant ignored (so in the `.gitignore` file). But adding the `--all` flag to the first command you write, does exactly what I want. Thanks for pointing me to this.